# How exactly does 'until $@' work in bash scripts?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I recently got a host where java apps are launched this way:

```
/bin/bash ./restarter.sh java <lot of java params>
```

It ensures that if the app dies, then `restarter.sh` runs it again.

There is content of `restarter.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
until "$@"; do
  echo "Server crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
  sleep 1
done
```

Please help me to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means to loop until the command("$@") completes execution with a exit code of 0.

Example:

```
$ until (echo Myprog ; sleep 1; exit 1;); do echo Error respawning ...; done
Myprog
Error respawning ...
Myprog
Error respawning ...
Myprog
^C

$ until (echo Myprog ; sleep 1; exit 0;); do echo Error respawning ...; done
Myprog
```

**Analyzing your script:**
Normally, a well written application would exit with exit code of zero on successful completion and non-zero exit code otherwise. In your case, you are using the until command to keep restarting the application:

```
java <lot of java params>
```

until the application completes its execution successfully(exit code of zero).